# Ubuntu 14.04 won't update packages

Tags: 14.04, updates, google-chrome

After installing the Chrome plugin 'Chrome Remote Desktop', Ubuntu fails to update its packages. I get a pop-up with the message:

```
Requires installation of untrusted packages
```

When I click 'OK' nothing further happens.

Do I have to uninstall 'Chrome Remote Desktop' or is there some work around?

Comment: try: `sudo apt-get update` then: `sudo apt-get upgrade` in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to install a package whose repository your Ubuntu does not trust.

### Possibility 1

Run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and find the missing key and install with

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://subkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys <your_missing_key>
```

### Possibility 2

But you can also use `y-ppa-manager`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

1. Run `y-ppa-manager`
2. Click `Advanced`
3. Click `Try to import all missing GPG keys`

Comment: @loldrup Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓).

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there is a problem with an apt source. Running `sudo apt-get update` should display what the error is, even when the system updater does not.

After you see what apt source is causing the error, you can fix that error or remove it from the configuration to allow the system to upgrade normally.

Answer (score 0):

I use synaptic package manager to deal with all the extra downloads that the software sources (if not configured correctly) aren't working properly. It also gives an option to mark all upgrades for every program you have in your computer (and driver), so I'd rather pick the lazy way and use synaptic..

If you'd like to check it out, its basically a graphical version of APT. https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic/